# Why Pentaho Data-integration cannot read new field on table?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-integration

I am trying to copy record from a few table into a new one(report_table). But when I've created the transformation on kettle, I need to add a new field into report_table. After I add the field, kettle wont show it. When I try to "enter field mapping", it does not show on 'target field' Why cant kettle read the field?

There's no special thing. I just put "Input Table" and give it a query to select from my resource table. Then I put "Output Table" and give a "Hop" between input and output table. Then when I choose "Enter field mapping" kettle can't read all field from target table.

Any idea.

Comment: please mention the steps you followed for doing above thing it will give clear idea for soling your problem.

Comment: I have add it. Hope it give a clue for you and the others.

Comment: if you only did the above things then how can you add new field to report_table?
if you create report_table into your database and then you specify target schema and target table and after that if you will press enter-field mapping it will show the the all fields coming from your "few table" ...

Comment: Yes, it works well before I add new field to report_table. After I add new field into report_table, the field does not show on target table.

Comment: how you added new field that is my question to you.. and the newly created field is present in report_table?

Comment: I add manually on pgadmin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clear the database cache. PDI caches the database structure, and also the hop metadata.

Also, i've seen bugs in 5.0.x where it gets into its head the structure of the metadata and will not change until you restart spoon. So try that too!  (Note this only happens occasionally in my experience, and I work with PDI all day every day.